# How do I tell if I've Carbon or Cocoa installed on my Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, cocoa

I need to compile some program with either Cocoa or Carbon windowing system. I have a 10.6.8 Snow Leopard installed on a i386 (at least `uname -a` tells me this) system. I opened the system-profiler and selected > Software > Frameworks. There are listed among others:

```
CarbonCore
CarbonSound
Cocoa
```

Does that mean, I am free to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of - [cocoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29) is the modern API for newer applications, and least with the latest versions of OS X, the preferred one.

[Carbon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_%28API%29) is a legacy API, used in OS 8 and 9 and is depreciated with the upcoming OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion . Some applications for OS X however continued using the carbon API until recently - wikipedia states older versions of photoshop, itunes and final cut were coded with carbon, though modern versions are cocoa based.

As a developer, you should be using cocoa over carbon, since cocoa supports 64 bits and well, isn't obsolete. In this case picking cocoa over carbon is a good idea.

As a user, this should be transparent to you, but you'd be using what API your software uses, assuming its supported.

I am guessing however compiling for either should work.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that Cocoa and Carbon are APIs. I just recently managed to boot into 64bit and I will use Cocoa interface.